# Constraints mess up after second rotation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, constraints

I'm trying to recreate the default iOS keyboard for some practice. I use the visual format language to create some constraints, as seen below:

```
var row1Constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-row1_LeftEdgeX-[button01(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button02(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button03(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button04(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button05(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button06(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button07(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button08(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button09(buttonWidth)]-buttonGapX-[button10(buttonWidth)]-row1_RightEdgeX-|",
                options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0),
                metrics: metrics,
                views: views)

        view.addConstraints(row1Constraint)
```

That constraint is for Portrait Mode, I also have constraints for Landscape Mode. I am using a very simple **if (view.bounds.width == CGFloat(320))** to determine the orientation and it works just fine. These constraints are inside a function named **setButtonConstraints()** that I call like this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    view.removeConstraints(view.constraints())
    setButtonConstraints()
}
```

This works great, and this is what the keyboard looks like when the code is build and run:

[image]

And when I rotate the device for the first time the constraints are flawless:

[image]

However, the problem occurs when I rotate the device back to portrait mode, all the UIButtons at the end of the their row disappear, as shown below:

[image]

The next orientation change to Landscape will be flawless again, but after another round of orientation changes the Portrait is fine but the Landscape ends up looking like this:

[image]

This happens in the simulator and on the device. I have been scratching my head for 2 days trying to figure out why the constraints would act like this. Any help would be **much** appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried overriding `updateViewConstraints` instead of `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and doing your constraint updates in there?

Comment: Actually, I decided to use viewWillLayoutSubviews after discovering that the constraints do not work when setting them through updateViewConstraints, oddly enough.

Comment: I have discovered that when I remove the last part of the layout format language string -row1_RightEdgeX-| the constraints don't mess up, but this does not feel like a final solution.